# php array get positions of the specific value

Tags: php, arrays, position

I have one array and I want to get the positions of one specific value

Example:

```
$my_array = array(0,2,5,3,7,4,5,2,1,6,9);
```

My search is *Number 5* the positions of *Number 5* in array was (*2* and *6*)

If i call the `array_search` function, always returns the first position in array witch is *2*.

Is there anyway to get the two ore more positions of specific value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [array_keys](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the optional search parameter, that should return all of the keys.

`$matches = array_keys($my_array, 5);`

Comment: Yes Thank you that is much better using array_keys thanks christian.thomas

Comment: what if array keys are changed.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) second parameter. You can get the keys only matching `$search_value`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array:

```
/* Searches $haystack for $needle.
   Returns an array of keys for $needle if found,
   otherwise an empty array */
function array_multi_search($needle, $haystack) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($haystack as $key => $value)
    if ($value === $needle)
      $result[] = $key;
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
   {
      $result[$value] =implode(',',array_keys($array,$value))

  }
  echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

it will give you an array with values as key and their occurrences as values separated by comma