# Ordering an array and then allocating a position based on where elements are

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array **$orderedUsers** in which I have sorted user ID's in a particular order. E.g. $orderedUsers=[6][4][11][2][18][7][5][10][12]. I will be using the order of this array to show a leaderboard based on where the users are in the array, so what I am asking is: how would I get the position of each element in the array. In the above example USERID=6 would be FIRST, USERID=4 would be SECOND, USERID=11 would be THIRD and so on...

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: You will find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159136/php-array-get-positions-of-the-specific-value

Comment: use `array_keys(array ($arr))` to get the index.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is search the array for a user ID. I then want to store the position of that user in a variable. EG. $userPosition = array_keys($orderedUsers, $userID); <-- with that code am I saying search the array for the chosen ID and assign it to the $userPosition variable?

Answer (score 0):

`array_search($needle,$haystack);

```
$available_colors = ['red','blue','yellow','orange','green'];

$color_position = array_search('yellow', $available_colors)); // 2
```

Comment: So what I am trying to do is search the array for a user ID. I then want to store the position of that user in a variable. EG. **$userPosition = array_keys($orderedUsers, $userID);** <-- with that code am I saying search the array for the chosen ID and assign it to the $userPosition variable?